# How to get a more Linux like experience on Android?

Tags: linux

Are there projects (e.g. ROMs) out there that offers a more Linux like experience on Android?

Here are some things that I hope for

- easy installation on similar platforms
- shell access
- development tools such as gcc, Python

Comment: What's "easy installation on similar platforms"?

Comment: From Stackoverflow: [Is there any way to run Python on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/101754/352449). I would recommend you to search at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) about GCC and Python, due to the nature of those applications.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I'd like something similar to Debian that can run on a variety of platforms without much work by the end user.

Comment: On the multiple platforms and and Linux-like part, see the new [Ubuntu Phone OS](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone), [How does the Ubuntu Phone OS relate to the Android OS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37160/), though installing that will mean that you won't be running Android on your phone at all anymore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are quite a few options already:

- Chroot to a full fledged linux (search for [debian chroot android](https://www.google.com/search?q=chroot+debian+android), it's got quite a few hits)
- There are also native ports of [Debian](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=debian%20on%20the%20site:xda-developers.com) or [Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20on%20the%20site:xda-developers.com&oq=ubuntu%20on%20the%20site:xda-developers.com) for some phone/tablet models.
- Shell access is already there: [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)
- If you install an aftermarket firmware such as [CyanogenMod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) you will get  root access, busybox, bash, an ssh client/server amongst other things
- Here's the [SL4A project](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (scripting layer for android), it adds python, lua, perl and other interpreted languages to android
- You can build Qt applications (yes, even those using QtGui) using [Necessitas](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/) -- a port of most parts of the Qt Desktop framework to Android. Applications as complex as Quassel (an IRC client/server) can be built with very minimal source changes. In theory this would allow you to build much of KDE4, though some parts (e.g. the Plasma workspace) may be too heavily tied to Xorg/GLX.
- Most C/C++ programs from GNU/Linux that do not require a graphical interface can be compiled to run on Android using the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

  - You can also use [Qpython3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpy3&hl=en) for python in android .
    Features:
- Run Python3 applications including script
  and projects on Android device
- Execute Python3 Code & File From QRCode
- Support SL4A Programming, can access
  android's feature, like network, bluetooth,
  location
- Support Python3 console
- Support QEdit which allow you edit Python
  code
  Support FTP server, which can let you
  transfer the Python3 project from your PC to
  mobile easily

  - You can use [kbox](http://www.kevinboone.net/kbox.html) for linux utilities on your non-rooted android device.
  - [Expand the Linux Capabilities on Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_bVC0x4l-g) video shows how to install busybox without root.
- Other things, you aware of. Feel free to add it here

Comment: If you feel your answer is incomplete and want to invite people to update it, you should make it Community Wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @AlEverett, was my 1st time to do so.

Comment: Always happy to help.

Comment: [botbrew](https://github.com/jyio/botbrew) is a fairly neat package manager for Android, too. Gives you some useful utilities like `make`, `git`. And since it's a package manager, you can add a ton more.